# Kaggleで「エキスパート」Tierになれる基準は何ですか？

Tags: 機械学習, kaggle

#### Kaggleとは

Kaggleのサイトへ行くと一番上に書かれていますが「The Home of Data Science & Machine Learning」（データサイエンスと機械学習の家）と題されている通り、世界中の機械学習・データサイエンスに携わっている約40万人の方が集まるコミニティーです。
https://www.kaggle.com/

#### エキスパートとは

Kaggleの最大の目玉とも言えるコンペがKaggleの特徴の一つです。コンペは、企業や政府がコンペ形式で課題を提示し、賞金と引き換えに最も制度の高い分析モデルを買い取るというものです。そして、そのランクには、エキスパート、マスター、グランドマスターがあります。

#### 質問

そこで、まずは手始めにエキスパートを目指そうと思っていますが、その基準がわかりません。どなたがご存知の方がいましたら、教えて頂けないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3):

Expert になる基準というだけであれば、公式ページに書いてあります: https://www.kaggle.com/progression

> **Expert**
>
> You’ve completed a significant body of work on Kaggle in one or more categories of expertise. Once you’ve reached the expert tier for a category, you will be entered into the site wide Kaggle Ranking for that category.
>
> - Competitions: 2 bronze medals
> - Kernels: 5 bronze medals
> - Discussions: 50 bronze medals

Comment: ありがとうございます。気が付きませんでした。ところで、これらのブロンズメダルを取得する基準について何かご存知であるか、参照するものがあれば教えて頂けないでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: リンクした同じページに書いてあります。